# Select records from table A where 4 of its columns equal to 4 of table's B columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Basically, I have two tables, a [students] table and a [units_allocation] table.
Both tables have columns named course_abbr, course_name, month_of_admission and year_of_admission.

I want to select records from the students table where the above 4 columns in both tables have similar values.

Comment: Please TAG the **RDBMS** you are using. Don't TAG everything under sun

Comment: thanks...just did that on the tags issue. Also, It might help if i show all the columns in both tables.

Comment: What query have you tried and what were the results?  You can edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is using [`INTERSECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188055.aspx)(work's for *SQL Server* and *Oracle*)

```
SELECT course_abbr, course_name, month_of_admission,year_of_admission 
FROM students
INTERSECT
SELECT course_abbr, course_name, month_of_admission,year_of_admission 
FROM units_allocation
```

or use `EXISTS` in case of `Mysql`

```
SELECT *
FROM   students s
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   units_allocation u
               WHERE  s.course_abbr = u.course_abbr
                      AND s.course_name = u.course_name
                      AND s.month_of_admission = u.month_of_admission
                      AND s.year_of_admission = u.year_of_admission)
```

Comment: Instead of thanking mark any one of the solution as answer :) Which will help the future readers

Answer (score 1):

An inner join or exists is a typical solution:

```
select s.*
from students s
where exists (select 1
              from units_allocation ua
              where s.course_abbr = ua.course_abbr and
                    s.course_name = ua.course_name and
                    s.month_of_admission = ua.month_of_admission and 
                    s.year_of_admission = ua.year_of_admission
              );
```